# How to make mod_cache work properly with dynamic content?

Tags: apache, caching, cgi

I'm trying to use mod_cache to cache dynamically generated content. This is my Apache config:

```xml
CacheEnable mem /
MCacheSize 4096
MCacheMaxObjectCount 100
MCacheMinObjectSize 1
MCacheMaxObjectSize 2048
CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
CacheStorePrivate On
CacheStoreNoStore On

<Location /cgi-bin>
    SetHandler cgi-script
    Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```

And this is one CGI script (just for testing):

```js
#!/opt/app/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs
var date = new Date('Sun, 01 Jan 2012 00:00:00 GMT');
console.log('Last-Modified: '+ date.toUTCString());
console.log('Cache-Control: max-age=' + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)+ ', public');
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 365);
console.log('Expires: '+ date.toUTCString() + '\n\n');

// lengthy operation here...

console.log(content);
```

This basically works. But **what happens** is if a client requests a cgi-bin with an `If-Modified-Since` header:

1. CGI-script streams headers
2. some seconds delay
3. CGI-script streams body
4. Apache sends 304

That makes no sense to me. Apache waits for the whole response before it sends a not-modified response.

**What I expected**:

1. CGI-script streams headers
2. Apache sends 304
3. CGI-script is canceled or body of CGI-script is discarded

Is there any way to get it done?

Comment: Additionally, I just found that mod_cache does not seem to have any effect at all when my cgi-script explicitly sets `Status: 200`, but it sends `304` if no Status header is sent by cgi.

Answer (score 0):

The CGI script should be changed as follows.

1. Don't use a static Last-modified date. The Last-Modified should be set for dynamic resources to the current execution time.
2. Cache Control directive contains a type error 'pulic' should be 'public'
3. Expires directive is not needed, because Cache-Control has a higher priority than Expires.

Your expected behavior "terminate CGI script" after sending header is not possible. If your cache works, the CGI script is not executed until the cache entry is invalidated.

Comment: 1. the above was just for testing. But the whole point of the question is that `last-modified` may or may not have changed between two requests (imagine concatenating different files...) 2. thanks for that, didn't change anything though. 3. I prefer to keep `Expires` just to be extra-safe. 4. "the CGI script is not executed until the cache entry is invalidated" How is that supposed to work with `if-modified-since`?

Comment: Aaaah - now I understand what you mean.
Your CGI script should sent status 304 if your resources has not changed, and abort further (body) processing. 

From apache doc:
When a conditional request is received by an origin server, the origin server should check whether the ETag or the Last-Modified parameter has changed, as appropriate for the request. If not, the origin should respond with a terse "304 Not Modified" response. This signals to the cache that the stale content is still fresh should be used for subsequent requests until the content's new freshness lifetime is reached again

Comment: Conditional client requests "if-modified-since" are satisfied by mod_cache if the entry is still valid (time valid) and the cache_control (origin response)  doen't contain the "must-revalidate" directive.

BTW: What apache version do you use?

Comment: Right. While Apache satisfies the requirement "the origin server should check whether the ETag or the Last-Modified parameter has changed" just fine, it does so by waiting for the complete response. Which renders caching useless. I use version 2.2, but might as well use 2.4

Comment: ... "Which renders caching useless" - i could not believe that and so i tried it out - and YES you are right - totaly useless in this combination :-(.
I did some further research why I never saw this behavior before in my project and found the answer - because we are forwarding requests for dynamic resource to other server instancesand then mod_cache will work. see the example in my next post

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i'm talking in my last comment. Forward the CGI execution to an internal virtual host. With this configuration mod_cache will work as expected. I tested it on my machine with apache 2.2.21.

```
# virtual cgi host - used internally only for cgi execution
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Project/web"
    ServerName cgi-bin.local
    ErrorLog "logs/cgi-bin-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/cgi-bin-access.log" combined
    LogLevel debug

    <Location /cgi-bin>
        SetHandler cgi-script
        Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>

# Virtual host used by client
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/Project/web"
    ServerName web.local
    ErrorLog "logs/web-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/web-access.log" combined

    CacheEnable mem /
    MCacheSize 4096
    MCacheMaxObjectCount 100
    MCacheMinObjectSize 50
    MCacheMaxObjectSize 20480
    MCacheMaxStreamingBuffer 20480
    CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
    CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
    CacheStorePrivate On
    CacheStoreNoStore On

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /cgn-bin http://cgi-bin.local:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /cgn-bin http://cgi-bin.local:8080/

</VirtualHost>
```